# How do I put gdb debugger under nohup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, background-process, nohup

i run my program in background as follows:

```
nohup ./program -c config.cfg &
```

So  i saw segmentation fault in my program and decided to run my program with `gdb`. My program has some infinite loops and may take some hours to deal with  a segmentation fault error, again.

So i want to run the program on background.

How should i pass the gdb arguments to `nohup`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried my hand at getting the `gdb` debugger to run in the background, but it's designed to be an interactive tool. I think what you are looking for here is a `screen`. A `screen` allows you to background the entire shell session by creating a virtual terminal.

Create the screen instance:

```
me@mybox$ screen -S my_screen_name
```

Then run:

```
me@mybox$ gdb --args ./program -c config.cfg
```

Once you are in the screen, `Ctrl-A-D` will detach the screen so you can go about your business and it will keep running.

To reattach:

```
me@mybox$ screen -r my_screen_name
```

Once you are done, type `Ctrl-D` in the screen to terminate the screen. For more help with screens, see `man screen`.

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you